# Sign Message Using private key instead of kesytore

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

I need to sign data using the private key and not keystore file. I can get data using:

```
var hash = "0x" + ethereumjs.ABI.soliditySHA3(
    ["address", "uint256", "uint256"],
    [web3.eth.defaultAccount, amount, nonce]
  ).toString("hex");
```

and sign the data using:

```
web3.personal.sign(hash, web3.eth.defaultAccount, callback);
```

But I am not sure how can sign this message using private key and without use of unlocking the account.

**I am not willing not use `personal` over RPC calls.**

Answer (score 1):

Try these three functions:

```
async function executeTransaction(transaction, value = 0) {
    return await signAndSendTransaction(transaction._parent._address, transaction.encodeABI(), value, 0);
}

async function transferEtherToContract(address, value) {
    return await signAndSendTransaction(address, "", value, 0);
}

async function transferEtherToAccount(address, value) {
    return await signAndSendTransaction(address, "", value, 21000);
}
```

All of which rely on this function:

```
async function signAndSendTransaction(to, data, value, gas) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            let options = {
                to   : to,
                data : data,
                value: value
            };
            options.gas = gas ? gas : (await web3.eth.getBlock("latest")).gasLimit;
            const signedTransaction  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, PRIVATE_KEY);
            const transactionReceipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTransaction.rawTransaction);
            return transactionReceipt;
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            console.log("Press enter to try again...");
            await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                process.stdin.resume();
                process.stdin.once("data", function(data) {
                    process.stdin.pause();
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in web3.js v1.0.0-beta.34 or earlier (and possibly later as well), function `web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction` may change the values in the `options` object passed to it.

They've fixed it at some point (via deep-cloning of this object), but I'm not sure which version.

Therefore, we initialize a new `options` object at every iteration.

In addition, since the latest block's gas-limit may change, we fetch it too at every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Web3js allows you to sign arbitrary data using the module accounts:

`web3.eth.accounts.sign(data, privateKey);`

You can find more in the [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=sign#sign)

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this function hashes the data as well. As you can see, I already have a hashed message, I want to simply sign it.

Comment: why Is this a problem? you sign it with this function and you send the original message with the signature. The recipient can verify the signature hashing your original message and passing it to the recover function together with the signature.

Comment: The problem is signing multiple arguments of different types, as I have asked in the question. `ethereumjs` provides better functionality of defining param types and then arguments in an array which produces the same hash as in solidity fn.

Comment: I think you are confused, you can get the hash with the method you are using and then use the function I postwd to sign that hash. Is irrelevant that the web3 function calculates the hash of the hash. In solidity you will pass the parameters and use abi.encodePacked and the the hash. You will be able then to verify the signature

Comment: **I do not need to verify the signature.** Say I have a couple for params (bytes32, address, uint) that I need to sign, I sign them from web3, send hashed message to smart contract. The smart contract also hashes the same params and checks if supplied hash matches the hash generated by it.  So in this case the solidity hashes my meesgae again and thus hash by SC and hash by web3 will not match. I am not sure if I am able to explain  my use case ;(

Comment: if you will not verify the signature, what is the purpose of signing it?. Also, again, what you are saying is not a problem. **if** the function is signing the hash of the message and your message is already a hash, the only thing you need to do in the contract is to hash the hash of the message.

Comment: I don't want to hash the message again in my contract. **Why do overcalculation in the smart contract**? And I need to verify the signature but I also need to verify the message that was signed. Like I give users a special text to sign, they sign it, then smart contract verifies the signature as well as the message. So it hashes the message it assigned to the user and check if provided hash is same or not.

Comment: Obviously the proposed solution of hasing message in contract again will work but It do not find it optimal. This is like I need to sign a message 'x' but the function will sign hash of 'x' and I have to again hash x in smart contract. This is just overcalculation and I will prefer not to go that way.

Comment: I recommend you to check how the signature is done. Hashing is an integral part cryptographic signature process and is not different from the function you posted as an answer. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55481/does-hash-than-sign-paradigm-apply-to-ecdsa-cryptography/55483#55483.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I can use same method to sign using private key as well.

**Sign Using unlocked account**

```
web3.eth.sign(msgHash, address, cb)
```

**Sign Using Private Key**

```
web3.eth.sign(msgHash, privKey)
```